# On a wireless network, is there a way to redirect webpages to a local page

Tags: networking, router, redirection

On a wireless network, I would like all traffic to a specific website to be re-directed to a page on a local server. I would like Query Strings to be left intact.

i.e. www.myvenue.com?memberId=1234 gets redirected to 127.0.0.1/myvenuelocal?memberId=1234
Is this possible?

We have an EE Bright Box WIFI router.

Here is some background on the reasons for wanting to do this as you may be able to think of a better solution:

- A friend of mine runs a venue in which members can use their own wireless devices to browse the internet via her WIFI router.
- The members of the venue all have membership cards with a QR code of the venues online website URL, so when scanned takes them their. This also has a query string for the members id (so the URL looks something like www.venuepage.com?memberid=1234) so that in the future they could do something on the site specific to each user.
- It has now been decided that they want to have a log-in system at the venue (no security is needed with this, it's just to track members and offer them rewards). As the members already have cards with QR codes and member ID's I wrote a small offline webpage that scans the code and logs the member in. However, it would be nice if the users could use their own devices rather than a PC in the corner. Accessing the local page on their devices is a bit of hassle and the experience is poor on iPhones as the webpage can not access a video stream from the camera.
- The solution we thought of was to allow the users to scan the QR code in any QR reader app (or even just browse to the url with the member id) and redirect them to a local page which would extract the member ID and use that to log them in. This is where I get stuck as I know nothing about routers and networking.

Many thanks.
N

Comment: the fact that it's wireless is irrelevant, you'd need the wired or wireless router to do this. I don't know how but you could do it if it's a linux router. Second to that, is maybe some standard router firmware can do it likee DDWRT or tomato. You'd need a router that supports it and flash it with that. And you'd need to find out how and if it's possible to do it in DDWRT ot tomato or any router firmware.